Change detection in ArcMap
I tried to do change detection using ArcMap. To do this I followed the following steps.

Convert from raster to polygon via "value" field (aware as I have 7 classes)
Dissolve through dissolve geoprocessing tool via "gridcode" field. However, here instead of producing 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7 classes it gives me 1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,and 7 dissolved classes. So, I need to have 1,2,3,4,5,6,and 7 classes(how can adjust this)
I tried to Intersect geoprocessing tool via following the above steps but it brings to the following error:


the background processing has encountered a serious error and is
unable to continue".

How do I solve this?

There are too many potential causes of something like this, and most of them indicate your software install is corrupt. Reinstalling the software is indicated (with all the recommended/security patches). After that you should test with background geoprocessing disabled, and then again with it enabled.

You don't need to convert raster->vector to do change detection, it can be done as raster.

Dear mates in this group, I haven't solved the above problem yet. Especially when I dissolve instead of forming 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, classes it is giving me 1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6, and 7. So, help me to figure out the problem
